# Can't change height using AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to change the height of a textarea using AngularJS within a directive. I add an attribute `auto-resize` to my `textarea` and have the directive defined as:

```
app.directive('autoResize',function(){
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //scope: {},
            replace: false,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.css({
                        'overflow': 'hidden',
                        'color': 'red',
                        'height': '50px'
                    });
                }

            }
        }
```

The color and overflow styles are implemented onto the textarea, however the height of the text-area does not go to 50px.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: may be textarea is displayed inline, set display to block and see what if it works, or try with !important...

Comment: This code works fine (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EwcrwPIr1NhSkeSRf9HI?p=preview)). Perhaps there is some other problem elsewhere? Are there other directives or css affecting the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directive might do what you're looking for :)

Here is a codepen showing it working:  https://codepen.io/benshope/pen/xOPvpm

```
app.directive('expandingTextarea', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
            $element.css('min-height', '0');
            $element.css('resize', 'none');
            $element.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
            setHeight(0);
            $timeout(setHeightToScrollHeight);

            function setHeight(height) {
                $element.css('height', height + 'px');
                $element.css('max-height', height + 'px');
            }

            function setHeightToScrollHeight() {
                setHeight(0);
                var scrollHeight = angular.element($element)[0]
                  .scrollHeight;
                if (scrollHeight !== undefined) {
                    setHeight(scrollHeight);
                }
            }

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return angular.element($element)[0].value;
            }, setHeightToScrollHeight);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the rows attribute on a textarea rather than changing the height through css.

```
app.directive('autoResize',function(){
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //scope: {},
            replace: false,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.css({
                        'overflow': 'hidden',
                        'color': 'red'
                    });
                    element.attr("rows", 5);
                }

            }
        }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp

Answer (score 0):

You must to use 'style' for manipulation of css attributes at the DOM level instead 'css()'. You can use the '.css()' method when you are using jQuery. Try this in your directive.

```
element.style.height = '50px';
element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
element.style.color = 'red';
```

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)